# MySQL 5.7 Unable to run query longer than 900 seconds

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a long-running query that continues to time out despite having set
DBMS connection read time out to 60000.
DBMS connection keep-alive-interval has been set to 6000.
It still constantly times out. It has to search over 1M records so the time isn't an issue.
I'm just having trouble getting the query to run over 900s.
The MySql server is running on a virtual machine running Windows server 2012.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This issue is different from the one it has been deemed a copy of can someone fixes this.

Comment: Even if it's too similar the solutions purposed on that thread do not solve this issue.